# Macro de Planilha de Excel - VBA - Erro de definição de aplicativo ou de definição de objeto (Concluída)

Tags: vba, excel-vba, macro

Estou criando uma macro pelo Botão de Comando ActiveX, onde o mesmo irá primeiramente selecionar células específicas, cada coluna por vez(AT2:AT15, BI2:BI15, BX2:BX15) e ordenar as mesmas de A até Z.

Após, nessas mesmas células, em cada coluna, em uma linha irá pintar o fundo de uma cor (branco) e na linha de baixo de outra cor (cinza), isso nas 14 linhas. Assim, cada uma tenho branco e outra cinza, sempre nessa ordem.

Porém, ocorreu o erro de definição de aplicativo ou de definição de objeto.

Estou utilizando a seguinte macro:

```
Private Sub ORDENAR_Click()
'
' Macro10 Macro
' as
'
' Atalho do teclado: Ctrl+Shift+P
'
    Range("BX2:BX15").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "BX2:BX15"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("BX2:BX15")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("BI2:BI15").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "BI2:BI15"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("BI2:BI15")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("AT2:AT15").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "AT2:AT15"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("AT2:AT15")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range( _
        "AT2,AT4,AT6,AT8,AT10,AT12,AT14,BI14,BI12,BI10,BI8,BI6,BI4,BI2,BX2,BX4,BX6,BX8,BX10,BX12,BX14" _
        ).Select
    Range("BX14").Activate
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range( _
        "BX15,BX13,BX11,BX9,BX7,BX5,BX3,BI3,BI5,BI7,BI9,BI11,BI13,BI15,AT15,AT13,AT11,AT9,AT7,AT5,AT3" _
        ).Select
    Range("AT3").Activate
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = -9.99786370433668E-02
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Ao Depurar me leva para a seguinte linha:

```
.Pattern = xlSolid
```

O erro somente acontece quando eu protejo a planilha, ou seja, quando a planilha está livre o código funciona corretamente.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Aqui funcionou conforme o esperado. Não avaliei se é a melhor forma de construção. Veja: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok, acredito que esqueci de comentar na pergunta, quando eu protejo a planilha que ocorre o erro, quando a planilha está desprotegida a macro funciona normalmente, caso tenha alguma maneira de fazer a macro funcionar com a planilha protegida, poderia me ajudar...

Comment: Edita e complementa com os detalhes do que realmente ocorre na pergunta. Acredito que terá mais sucesso na ajuda que busca.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro ocorre devido a proteção de edição na planilha. Abaixo duas opções de tratamento, entre outras possíveis dependendo de cada caso:

### Incluir etapa de desbloqueio no código

É possível controlar o bloquei e desbloqueio, através dos comandos:

```
Worksheets("Planilha1").Unprotect "AlterarParaaSuaSenhaAqui"
'[...código...]
Worksheets("Planilha1").Unprotect "AlterarParaaSuaSenhaAqui"
```

Observe que a **senha ficará salva e pode ser exposta** sempre que alguém acessar o editor de código da macro. Portanto, é recomendável que proteja o projeto VBA (Ferramentas/Propriedades de VBAProject/Proteção).

Exemplo aplicado ao código da pergunta:

```
Private Sub ORDENAR_Click()
'
' Macro10 Macro
' as
'
' Atalho do teclado: Ctrl+Shift+P
'

    Worksheets("Planilha1").Unprotect "AlterarParaaSuaSenhaAqui"

    Range("BX2:BX15").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "BX2:BX15"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("BX2:BX15")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("BI2:BI15").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "BI2:BI15"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("BI2:BI15")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("AT2:AT15").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "AT2:AT15"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("AT2:AT15")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range( _
        "AT2,AT4,AT6,AT8,AT10,AT12,AT14,BI14,BI12,BI10,BI8,BI6,BI4,BI2,BX2,BX4,BX6,BX8,BX10,BX12,BX14" _
        ).Select
    Range("BX14").Activate
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range( _
        "BX15,BX13,BX11,BX9,BX7,BX5,BX3,BI3,BI5,BI7,BI9,BI11,BI13,BI15,AT15,AT13,AT11,AT9,AT7,AT5,AT3" _
        ).Select
    Range("AT3").Activate
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = -9.99786370433668E-02
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
    Worksheets("Planilha1").Protect "AlterarParaaSuaSenhaAqui"
End Sub
```

### Permitir formatação ao bloquear

Ao deixar as células livres para formatação, mesmo com a planilha bloqueada, o código não terá problemas ao ser executado e a senha não precisa ser armazenada no mesmo. Porém, as células ficam livres para edição dos usuários também.

1. Planilha toda - Você pode permitir a formatação de células ao fazer o bloqueio, como por exemplo:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Células específicas - Você pode definidas algumas células/intervalos para não serem bloqueadas, selecione e Ctrl+1, em Proteção.

---

Enfim, há diferentes maneiras de solucionar o erro que está ocorrendo. É preciso avaliar o que se aplica melhor no caso em específico, considerando vantagens e desvantagens de cada uma das possíveis soluções.